# How to fetch data from node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to react and node and I'm trying to build a simple app to retrieve stock prices.

I'm able to reach my server route that I want but I'm getting a `FetchError: invalid json response body` from my server, what does this mean? How should I properly fetch an external api in my express route and send that data as a response?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    response: '',
    symbol: '',
  };

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let apiURL = `/stocks/${ this.state.symbol }/price`
    fetch(apiURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then( (result) => {
        this.setState({
          response: result
        })
      })
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </header>

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.symbol}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ symbol: e.target.value })}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p>{this.state.response}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// API routes
app.get('/stocks/:symbol/price', (req, res) => {
  const token = 'pk_5f69bda1e3074237a9d2e844a3dafbff'
  const symbol = req.params.symbol
  const apiURL = `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${symbol}/price?token=${token}`

  fetch(apiURL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      res.send({ data })
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "client": "yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

Comment: If I try this by hand, I get an invalid API key message. You probably obfuscated the key, but you might want to try ensuring that works first. Are you sure the backend is successfully returning to the front end? This would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Can you post us the API response from POSTMan or something? Don't use browser. And please, if the `sk_blahblah` is real SK, I am going to raise a modflag so that your key isn't compromised. **Secret API tokens should be kept confidential and only stored on your own servers. Your account’s secret API token can perform any API request to IEX Cloud.**

Comment: I have revised my question with the publishable key from IEX. I was able to send a request to `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/AAPL/quote?token=Tpk_1be8526a198c4c298a3eb6e3fba5531c` and get a response.